# Save map with widget as video/html_video

Tags: python, widget, html5-video, ipywidgets

I created a map with a widget. The widget looks as following:

```
time_slider = widgets.interactive(var_map_interactive, time_sel=widgets.IntSlider(description = "Time", min = 0, max = t_end, step = 5, readout_format = "d"), continous_update = True)
```

I now wanted to save this as a widget stream using the WidgetStream from ipywebrtc

```
view_stream = WidgetStream(widget=time_slider)
```

and then as a VideoRecorder

```
recorder = VideoRecorder(stream=view_stream)
```

However, eventhough the map with the widget works on its own in my Jupyter notebook, the "recorder" does not display anything.
Any ideas why this is happening?

Also, how would I be able to create a html_video out from the recording?

Thanks for your help!